# Como puedo usar variables de entorno de un .env en diferentes proyectos?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, env

Estoy en busca de una solución que me permita usar las variables de entorno del .env en diferentes archivos de proyectos. En el repositorio que tengo hay varios subproyectos que son el conjunto de un proyecto, subproyectos de frontend y microservicios. La estructura del repositorio es algo así:

```
-Poyecto
 -frontend_1
   -public
   -src
   package.json
 -frontend_2
 -frontend_3
 -microservicio_frontend_1
 -microservicio_frontend_2
 -microservicio_frontend_3
.env
.gitignore
docker-compose.yml
```

Cada directorio es un proyecto especifico y con sus demas archivos que conforman dicho proyecto. El .env se utiliza basicamente en el archivo docker-compose.yml, pero ahora lo que busco es tomar dicho .env y usar las variables digamos en frontend_1 el cual esta desarrollado con el framework Vue.js.

He intentado en el main.js importar las variables de dicha manera:

```
require('dotenv').config({ path: '../../.env' })
```

Despues intento en alguna de mis vistas a traves de un mounted ver si se cargaron las variables mediante un console:

```
mounted() {
 console.log(process.env)
}
```

Pero no obtengo las variables que estan en el .env por lo que no se estan cargando.

Alguien que me pueda guiar de que manera poder lograr esto o decirme si es posible hacerlo por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de como esté construido el proyecto de Vue.

Si usaste Vue Cli:

[Según la documentación](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables), para que las variables de entorno tengan efecto dentro del proyecto de Vue con Vue Cli tienen que estar prefijadas con `VUE_APP_`. Es decir, si tu variable se llama por ejemplo `BACKEND_URL`, para ser vista desde el proyecto de Vue (En el frontend) debería ser llamada `VUE_APP_BACKEND_URL`.

Si usas Vite:

[Según la documentación](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html#env-files), es probable que tenga que ver con como accedes a las variables de entorno. En vez de usar `process.env` deberías usar `import.meta.env`. Junto con esto, puede que igual debas usar un prefijo como en Vue Cli, en este caso sería `VITE_`.

La idea detrás de usar los prefijos es que no se expongan variables en el lado del cliente que podrían contener información delicada (Como una variable de entorno con las credenciales de una base de datos).